# C++ Copy values of one object into another object

Tags: c++, class, copy

I have

```
Class A
{
    A(bool t1, bool t2, bool t3......................bool tn );
}
```

and

```
Class B
{
    B(bool t1, bool t2, bool t3.......................bool tn);
}
```

Both classes have same structure , I want to extract all bool values from Class A `obj1`  and pass it to Class B `obj2` .

If I get value of each bool variable from `obj1` and pass it to `obj2` ... it will make code very huge .

I used reinterpret_cast to solve this problem however I got c++ lint warning 826 http://stellar.cleanscape.net/products/cpp/checks.html .

Comment: Using `reinterpret_cast` here is such a horrible idea it's not even funny. If you have so many bools and don't want to pass them value by value, how about storing a `vector<bool>` and simply copying that over? Or a `map<string, bool>` if you want to maintain their names.

Comment: If your classes have common parts, these parts should be abstracted into a class of its own.

Comment: Personally I do this using encapsulation by passing the settings around as structs/objects/collections. Rather than bool t1 ..tn, it should take a `std::array<bool,n>`. Whenever you have .................... arguments your interface smells.

Comment: If you want to maintain the discrete names and not put them in a vector, make a struct that has all the bools. Have the classes contain that struct and pass that struct around.

Comment: Is the arity (value of `n`) fixed, or does it vary? How large is it really? IMO `n=2` isn't really a problem, but large or variable `n` would be.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a constructor for class b that takes class a as a parameter, in the constructor you would do the assignment. 
Or you could overload the = operator. Ultimately you could do:

```
class b = class a;
```

if you take the route of overloading the = operator.

You can read about the copy constructors and operator = here: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/911-the-copy-constructor-and-overloading-the-assignment-operator/

A word of caution, make sure to read the article if you choose the = operator route because it takes some getting used to.

Comment: this only works if the bools are saved in the class and not just flags or something else.

Answer (score 2):

Pass a std::vector as argument holding bool values from 1 to n. Why do even you have so much single variables instead of a vector?

Make

```
B(bool t1, bool t2, bool t3.......................bool tn);
```

To

```
B(std::vector<bool>& booleanValues);
```

Pass booleanValues to A so you get this code:

```
B(std::vector<bool>& booleanValues)
{
     A(booleanValues);
}
```

Comment: Good job. Personally, I'd make sure to pass it as a const reference. Also one should make sure to deal intelligently with not supplying n arguments

Comment: Hmm making it const would be better, since you can't mess with it. But sometimes it is funny to mess with given references ^^.

Answer (score 1):

well, the real question is weather the classes are the same, have the same struct, have some parts that are the same or is one of them is kind of the other kind.

- same class: use only 1 class and create as much instance as you need
- same struct: if they have the same struct but different methods you can make a parent class or leave them as they are, cus' same struct doesn't necessarily say same meaning.
- are the same or is one of them is kind of the other kind: this probably say inheritance. you'll need to decide based on logic which parts are supposed to go to the parent class and weather the parent class should be abstract, or i A parent of B, the other way around or a new parent class for both

Answer (score 1):

You can do copy constructor (and also conversion constructors) and operator= as mentioned in another answer, and put all the bools in an array as also mentioned in another answer. If you need or want the bools to have discrete variable names, you can put them in a struct and use that struct to pass the values. This code just passes the struct around with a Get() and Set(): If you do a copy constructor and operator= the struct isn't necessary since the large assignment code is hidden in  member functions and not seen when passed from object to object. But it may be best to retain it if the different types of objects will always contain the same set of bools and the bools are all related in some way.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct States {
  bool left;
  bool right;
  bool up;
  bool down;
};

class A {
  States states;
public: 
  A (bool left, bool right, bool up, bool down) : states {left,right,up,down} {}
  void Print(void) { 
    cout << states.left << ',' << states.right << ',' << states.up << ',' << states.down << endl;
  }
  void Set(const States &states) { this->states = states; }
  const States &Get(void) { return states; }
};

class B {
  States states;
public:
  B (bool left, bool right, bool up, bool down) : states {left,right,up,down} {}
  void Set(const States &states) { this->states = states; }
  const States &Get(void) { return states; }
  void Print(void) { 
    cout << states.left << ',' << states.right << ',' << states.up << ',' << states.down << endl;
  }
};

int main()
{
  A a(true,false,true,false);
  a.Print();
  B b(true,true,true,true);
  b.Print();
  b.Set( a.Get() );
  b.Print();
  B bb(false,false,false,false);
  a.Set( bb.Get() );
  a.Print();
}
```